# Html Agility not working with a string from an async method

Tags: c#, async-await, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the HTML of a website that is javascript heavy, then use HtmlAgilityPack to analyze the HTML received.

I am getting the desired response, however, when trying to load the data using this line

```
var docB = fromDoc.LoadHtml(docBContent);
```

Visual studio is having none of it, saying the following:

> cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

Full code:

```
var fromDoc = new HtmlDocument();
var docBContent = await renderHtmlAsync(url2);
var docB = fromDoc.LoadHtml(docBContent); // error


public static async Task<string> renderHtmlAsync(string url2)
{
    await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
    Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = true
    });
    var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    page.DefaultTimeout = 0;
    var navigation = new NavigationOptions
    {
        Timeout = 0,
        WaitUntil = new[] {
                WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded }
    };
    await page.GoToAsync(url2, navigation);
    var content = page.GetContentAsync();

    return await content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you dosnt need asign `fromDoc.LoadHtml(docBContent);` to variable.

```
 var fromDoc = new HtmlDocument();
 var docBContent = await renderHtmlAsync(url2);
 fromDoc.LoadHtml(docBContent);
```

and now you can use formDoc.

like:

```
var data = fromDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div");
```